# No menu or setup for Sound Juicer

Tags: mp3, sound-juicer

I have installed Sound juicer on my 19.10 only laptop and via the Ubuntu Software Installer and via Synaptic. In both cases there is no setup menu at all. It is not in the topbar as you can see from this screenshot.I cannot say where I want the MP3s to be stored and so on. [image]

Comment: Is this https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2289731  helpful?

Comment: Thanks, but no, it didn't help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting Sound Juicer prferences](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217102/setting-sound-juicer-prferences)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same, with wayland wich is the default Ubuntu option. Choose Ubuntu (xorg) from the option wheel on the session connect panel and the menu will be back

Answer (score 0):

There's a newer version of Soundjuicer, which has the menu back (in the application-bar, not in the gnome-bar)
https://www.mail-archive.com/ubuntu-bugs@lists.ubuntu.com/msg5870294.html